# New for iOS 9 "fbauth2" missing from Info.plist

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

When I attempt to do a Facebook login, I get the following message on console:

```
FBSDKLog: fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0
```

I presume this is newly added for iOS 9.0, as none of the docs say anything about it. It's a bit cryptic for me, does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Just a Google search of LSApplicationQueriesSchemes finds the answer.

Comment: I disagree. Facebook integration on apps is much more important than instagram, its the universal login for mobile applications, this post should be open to allow facebook specific solutions to this problem

Comment: Facebook has posted detailed documentation about this issue at the following link. Hopefully it will help those who are in need of it. I still say this should not be closed.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9. The problem is with LSApplicationQueriesSchemes but the keys that facebook requires to be whitelisted to fix the problem are specific and not mentioned in the Instagram post.